# Wine 1.9.24 and Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, centos-7, wine

### The problem

When I try to start any windows program I get no error and nothing happens. I tried on 3 different machines with Centos 7. Also tried older versions of Wine. Tested with winbox.exe from Mikrotik and with putty.exe. What could be the problem?

```
$ ./wine winbox.exe
$
```

#### CentOS 7 version

```
$ cat /etc/*elease | grep "release" | head -1
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

#### Kernel version

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

#### Openbox version

```
$ openbox --version | grep "Openbox"
Openbox 3.5.2
```

### Wine install steps

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install -y libX11-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel libxcb-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libjpeg-devel gnutls-devel flex bison

cd /tmp
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/1.9/wine-1.9.24.tar.bz2
tar xjf wine-1.9.24.tar.bz2
cd wine-1.9.24

./configure  --enable-win64
make -j4
```

and the executable is working

```
$ ./wine --version
wine-1.9.24
```

Comment: Is installing wine using `yum` an option?

Comment: got the same result after installing wine with `yum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### wine-2.0-rc3

Had no time to try the latest Wine 2.0 version, but all my problems are gone with wine-2.0-rc3. Tested only 32bit install. Step by step:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum groupinstall -y 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install -y libX11-devel freetype-devel zlib-devel libxcb-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libjpeg-devel gnutls-devel flex bison
sudo yum install -y samba-winbind samba-winbind-clients samba-winbind-modules libwbclient-devel mod_auth_ntlm_winbind
# OpenGL support
sudo yum install mesa-dri-drivers.i686 mesa-libGL.i686

mkdir ~/bin && cd ~/bin
wget http://dl.winehq.org/wine/source/2.0/wine-2.0-rc3.tar.bz2
tar xjf wine-2.0-rc3.tar.bz2 && cd wine-2.0-rc3

# run provided install tool and write the output to file
./tools/wineinstall | tee output.file

# get the winetricks tool
wget  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks
chmod +x winetricks 
WINE=~/bin/wine-2.0-rc3/wine sh winetricks corefonts vcrun6 mfc40 ie8

# start the downloaded windows program
./wine ~/Downloads/winbox.exe
```

### winbox from Mikrotik

[image: winbox]

### SketchUp

[image: winbox]

Answer (score 0):

Building and running wine inside `/tmp` may be the problem. `/tmp` is usually a place where programs create temporary files while they are running, but there is no guarantee these files will be persistent. Try building and running inside of your home directory, or even better install using your package manager `yum` to ensure compatibility with your OS.

Comment: I use `~/bin` for building and running apps. for temporary tests I use `/tmp`